# How do I add a servlet to spring framework java web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, web-applications

I thought this would be pretty straightforward, but apparently I'm missing something, and I can't seem to figure out what it is.

I'm trying to add a servlet to an existing web application written using java and spring. Here's what I did:

I added the following to web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SettingServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>SettingServlet</display-name>
    <description>Provides a rest endpoint for getting and setting settings.</description>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/SettingServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SettingServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/setting/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then I created the following file (.../WEB-INF/SettingServlet-servlet.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd"
>

<bean id="settingController"
  class="com.my.package.path.SettingController"
  p:settingService-ref="settingService"/>

</beans>
```

Then I created the following Controller (com.my.package.path.SettingController.java):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/setting")
public class SettingController {
    private SettingService settingService;
    public void setSettingService(final SettingService settingService) {
        Validate.notNull(settingService, "SettingController::settingService cannot be null");
        this.settingService = settingService;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Secured({ "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR", "ROLE_CURIOUS_GEORGE" })
    public ResponseEntity<String> getSettingRequest(@PathVariable("name") final String name, @RequestParam("setting_family") final String settingFamily) {
        final String jsonBody = "{\"setting\":\"" + name + "\", \"Setting Family\":\"" + settingFamily + "\", \"value\":\"test\"}";
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonBody, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG? :(  I get a 404 not found exception when trying to do a GET request at /setting/fruit?setting_family=foods

Comment: In xml that's not treated as a comment :) That's to direct anything (*) with the base of /setting/... to my SettingController...

Comment: as you declared url pattern to your dispatcher as "/setting/*" and then in controller you declared "/setting" as a root requestMapping for this controller, you should be able to access your controller using this url:
/setting/setting/fruit?setting_family=foods

Comment: YESSSSS!!!! Thank you Babur, that was it. If you repost your comment as an answer to my question, I'll mark it as THE answer. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you declared url pattern to your dispatcher as "/setting/*" and then in controller you declared "/setting" as a root requestMapping for this controller, you should be able to access your controller using this url: /setting/setting/fruit?setting_family=foods
:)